# Unknown exception when exporting video asset

Tags: ios, photosframework

I have the following code to export video data from Photos:

```
if (asset.mediaType == PHAssetMediaTypeVideo)
{
    [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:asset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset *asset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
        AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
        exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeQuickTimeMovie;
        [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^{
            [[SharedManager sharedInstance] insertAttachment:exportSession.outputURL forEvent:event];
        }];
    }];
}
```

This code rises an unidentified exception (with breakpoints disabled) on the line with [exportSession export...] thing.
ExportSession is valid, but shows `outputFileType = (null)` in the log, so I had to set it manually.

I can see the URL of the video, something like file://private.mobile....MOV, it was captured by camera and is stored in the assets catalog (I can watch it with Photos). It has 2 seconds length.

Please, help me out. How to export video file using Photos?

> P.S.: Exporting of images using PHImageManager works perfectly fine.

Comment: You say "unidentified exception"...what do you actually see?

Comment: I see just an exception (application breaks) telling something like EXC_BREAKPOINT <some numbers> pointing to the line with [exportSession exportAsynchronously...].

Comment: If it says breakpoint and you really have no breakpoints set, it sounds as if Xcode is confused.

Comment: please, check my edited question

Comment: Have you tried [PHImageManager requestExportSessionForVideo:options:exportPreset:resultHandler:] ? (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHImageManager/requestExportSessionForVideo:options:exportPreset:resultHandler:)

Comment: Yes, that was the first approach. The same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've found the issue. 
It is not said in the documentation, but it is required that outputURL set manually. So the following peace of code (from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20244790/773451) is required:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *outputURL = paths[0];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager createDirectoryAtPath:outputURL withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
outputURL = [outputURL stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
// Remove Existing File
[manager removeItemAtPath:outputURL error:nil];
exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputURL];
```