# How to trim 10 seconds from a UIImagePicker selected video iOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm using UIImagePicker to select an existing video from gallery. And then I want to crop only 10 seconds form the selected video. And Is there a way to set video trim slider to 10 seconds on image picker ?

Comment: Go through this link for video trimming http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244456/how-to-trim-the-video-file-and-convert-to-15-seconds-video-with-ios-sdk